# Chrome Extension - Pass message from background to content

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to pass a message from `background` script to `content` script ? How could it be done ? What I want to achieve is to read a config file from `background.js` and pass it to `content.js` script such that the content script can make use it to match some selectors and grab info from the current page. Is it right way to think about this ?

I have setup `background.js` to send a message like below after the file has been read using the `fetch` api via `chrome.runtime.getURL`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'configFile', config: json})
```

Comment: See the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation: 1) you can use chrome.tabs.sendMessage in the background script and specify the tab id as the first parameter; 2) alternatively, use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the content script and chrome.runtime.onMessage listener in the background script that sends a response with the config.

Comment: I'm trying the approach of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.  However i'm having trouble with getting the below code executed.         `console.log(`got message: , request.msg). 
        var cssSelectors = req.cssSelectors
        console.log(cssSelectors)` . I get `req.message` in console. However I'm not able to get `cssSelectors` in console as it expected in the last line - nothng gets printed. Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing from your comment. Did you read the documentation I've linked? It contains examples.

Comment: yes. And figured out a typo which needed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In your content script add

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage)
function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log(request); //logs "your message"
}
```

In background script add
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage("your message")`

There are a ton of other examples you can find on chrome add-ons documentation.